# Can copied videos with the same hash be added to the same dictionary for a duplicate detector?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a duplicate detector based on hashes. I've stumbled across a problem I don't know how to solve: I have a short mp4 file that I copied and is just named "bubblegum.mp4 Copy" and it has the same hash as "bubblegum.mp4". I'm at a point where I'm using the hash value as keys and the name of the videos as values, and I'm trying to append any videos with the same hash to the same corresponding key.

The problem is that this works for all videos except videos with the same hash. Instead of picking up both videos, it's simply only adding one to the corresponding key and leaving out the original file.

Is this just a feature of Dictionaries I wasn't aware of?

```
import hashlib, os, sys;
storage_Dictionary = {};
dupe_Finder = {};
parent = 'C:/Users/ryan6/Documents/python_related/';
files_To_Hash = tuple(os.listdir()); 

for video in files_To_Hash:
    with open(os.path.join(parent, video), 'rb') as content_Stream:
        content = content_Stream.read(); #read files in byte stream
        hashed = hashlib.sha256();
        hashed.update(content); #methods return None when assigned to variables
        storage_Dictionary[f'{video}'] = hashed.hexdigest();


# flip the values and keys, so you can see which keys have the same values
for i, v in storage_Dictionary.items():
    if v in dupe_Finder.items():
        dupe_Finder[v].append(i);
    else:
        dupe_Finder[v] = i;
print(dupe_Finder);
```

Comment: Not commenting on whether this is the best way to go or not, but your issue is most likely in the flip. `dupe_finder[v] = i` adds a `{ hash: file_name }` entry into the storage-dict, but then you won't be able to append to it - since you need an array to append to. Might want to change that to `dupe_finder[v] = [i]`. The other issue is the condition `v in dupe_finder.items()` - that can just be changed to `v in dupe_finder`; `.items()` gives you back an array of tuples (or a dict_items object in py3).

Comment: Ayee thank you for the solution, Wiggy! You made me realize that I had to look deeper into a dictionary's methods.